# Can you retrieve a discarded item in No Mans Sky?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I was wondering if it is at all possible to retrieve a discarded item? I recently miss clicked when not paying attention and discarded an atlas stone which seems to be pretty valuable... I thought it was a fascination bead, doh...

Comment: I just came up with a possible solution myself: reloading from a previous save! Of course this will depend if you have recently saved or not.

Comment: Post it as an answer then! That could potentially work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A possible solution could be to reload from a previous save! This depends heavily of course on the last time you saved the game though, although saves do occur frequently.

Answer (score 12):

As of right now, there is no way to recover discarded items. Once it's gone, it's gone. Consider it a lesson in double checking and close reading.

While I cannot find a solid online source for this, from my own experience with the game, there is no way.

Comment: On a related note, if you mine for materials but your suit is full, anything you mine will be discarded, never to be seen again.

Comment: @MageXy Thanks, I forgot about that! Also of note is that if your suit inventory is full, and you try to grab items out of crates, it won't let you pick it up, it will just say your suit is full. :)

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that there is a difference in inventory size between your suit and your ship. Your ship can hold stacks of 500 while your suit only supports 250.